# What is (are) difference between NOLOCK and UNCOMMITTED

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, locking, isolation-level

I use SQL Server 2012.

I write two queries but what is a different between `NOLOCK` and `UnCommitted` ?

```
SELECT lastname, firstname
FROM HR.Employees with (READUNCOMMITTED)

SELECT lastname, firstname 
FROM HR.Employees with (NoLock)
```

Comment: The documentation for `NOLOCK` states: `NOLOCK: Is equivalent to READUNCOMMITTED`. I guess that should answer your question. The relevant section in the Books Online is `Table Hints`if you feel like reading up on it further.

Comment: @jpw please give me a link

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373%28v=sql.110%29.aspx You can find the information in the documentation that is accessed via `F1`.

Comment: @jpw : merci pour F1

Answer (score 66, accepted):

**NOLOCK :** Is equivalent to `READ UNCOMMITTED` (source : **[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx)**)

`NOLOCK` or `READ UNCOMMITTED` Specifies that dirty reads are allowed. No shared locks are issued to prevent other transactions from modifying data read by the current transaction, and exclusive locks set by other transactions do not block the current transaction from reading the locked data. Allowing dirty reads can cause higher concurrency, but at the cost of reading data modifications that then are rolled back by other transactions

`READ UNCOMMITTED` and `NOLOCK` hints apply only to data locks. All queries, including those `with READ UNCOMMITTED and NOLOCK` hints, acquire Sch-S (schema stability) locks during compilation and execution. Because of this, queries are blocked when a concurrent transaction holds a Sch-M (schema modification) lock on the table

Answer (score 31):

No difference in terms of their functions, like other have mentioned.

The single difference is that you can apply `WITH(NOLOCK)` selectively, on some tables but not others. `READ UNCOMMITTED` applies `NOLOCK` to all tables in a session.

If you do this:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

SELECT *
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.id
```

It is functionally equivalent to:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 T1 WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 WITH(NOLOCK) ON T1.ID = T2.ID
```

But you can also apply `WITH(NOLOCK)` selectively:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 T1 WITH(TABLOCK)
INNER JOIN Table2 WITH(NOLOCK) ON T1.ID = T2.ID
```

Comment: Btw, the OP was asking about the synonymous table hints NOLOCK and READUNCOMMITED.

Answer (score 26):

**Under the hood they are the performing the same action.**

The `READ UNCOMMITTED` isolation level is the least restrictive isolation level within SQL Server, which is also what makes it popular for developers when looking to reduce blocking.

The `NOLOCK` table hint behind the scenes performs the exact same action as running under the read-uncommitted isolation level.

**The** **only difference** between the two is that the `READ UNCOMMITTED` isolation level determines the locking mechanism for the entire connection and the `NOLOCK` table hint determines the locking mechanism for the table that you give the hint to.

Answer (score 10):

There is no difference at the statement level.

You can set READUNCOMMITED at the session level and here you have to write
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

Answer (score 2):

For NOLOCK , we need to put this hint on table level, so it is require to put for every tables level which are used in update transaction. So it is very lengthy and time consuming to put it everywhere tables refers in query. For READ UNCOMMITTED, We do not need to put it every tables level, just put at session level or query level and can be written at top of the query or stored procedure. 
Let us look on small demo to elaborate it. First checking here database default isolation level

```
CREATE TABLE SAMPLETABLE
(
Col1 INT ,
Col2 VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO SAMPLETABLE(Col1,Col2)
SELECT 1,'Col1'
Union all
SELECT 2,'Col1'

BEGIN TRANSACTION 

Update SAMPLETABLE Set Col2 = 'Value changed' Where col1 =1

Select * from SAMPLETABLE with (nolock)



SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

Select * from SAMPLETABLE
```

Output is   1, Col1     for both query