# What is the TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL that is equivalent with (NOLOCK) for all select statements?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, locking

I am building a stored procedure for reporting and I am using (NOLOCK) for all select statements.

There is no locking requirement for the scenario I am working on.

I am thinking to change the TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL at the top of the stored procedure, and avoid adding (NOLOCK) to all of the select statements. Is there a TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL that is equivalent with (NOLOCK) when I set it at the top of the store procedures?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27198020/3270427

Comment: Probably a good idea to read this article. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/ NOLOCK is far more sinister than most people realize.

Comment: You could have gotten the answer by Googling 'Nolock transaction isolation level sql server'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL** : `READ UNCOMMITTED`

> Specifies that statements can read rows that have been modified by
>   other transactions but not yet committed. Transactions running at the
>   READ UNCOMMITTED level do not issue shared locks to prevent other
>   transactions from modifying data read by the current transaction. READ
>   UNCOMMITTED transactions are also not blocked by exclusive locks that
>   would prevent the current transaction from reading rows that have been
>   modified but not committed by other transactions. When this option is
>   set, it is possible to read uncommitted modifications, which are
>   called dirty reads. Values in the data can be changed and rows can
>   appear or disappear in the data set before the end of the transaction.
>   This option has the same effect as setting NOLOCK on all tables in all
>   SELECT statements in a transaction. This is the least restrictive of
>   the isolation levels.

**Note :** This is not a recommended Isolation level as this can allows dirty reads

If you want to set the `ISOLOATION LEVEL` to the SP alone then try changing the SP

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PRC_SP AS
BEGIN

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

--your statements 

END
```

Comment: Thank you for prompt help. Can you confirm that when I SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED, it **only** affects the stored procedure running the code? I don't want to change the ISOLATION LEVEL of the rest of the application.